# How to add dependency on a jar in Gradle while swaping internal library dependency

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add a jar dependency to my Android project:

```
dependencies {
  compile files('<SOME_JAR>')
}
```

But the jar is packaged with a library dependency I don't want to include. Instead I would like to declare a newer version of the library:

```
dependencies {
  compile '<NEW_VERSION_LIBRARY>'
  compile files('<SOME_JAR>') {
    exclude '<OLD_VERSION_LIBRARY>'
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this in Gradle?

Comment: You're saying the "SOME_JAR" jar has one or more jar files packaged within it, that you want to exclude?  You can't do that with dependency exclusions.  If you just want to use the new version, then just declare the dependency for the new version.

Comment: "SOME_JAR" has a static library dependency; the files of the library are copied within the jar, but the version of the library is older than what I want. The issue I'm having is that at runtime the app is linking against this old version instead of the newer version. I was looking for a workaround in Gradle but there doesn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 1):

If your dependencies are loading multiple versions of a given library, and you want to use a specific version, then you can do something like this, which will always use Groovy 2.4.5:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.codehaus.groovy') {
            details.useVersion '2.4.5'
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to keep from loading a particular dependency, because you'd prefer to use something else, then you want something like this, which will exclude the Apache Commons Logging and substitute SLF4J and Logback:

```
dependencies {
    compile ( "com.orientechnologies:orientdb-graphdb:2.0.7" ) { 
        exclude module:'commons-logging' 
    }
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12' 
    runtime 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.12' 
    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
}
```

Comment: But it seems there's no way to exclude and substitute if the dependency is packaged in a jar, right?

Comment: @Julian If you mean to exclude *classes* that are packaged in the jar, then yeah, no way. If you're dragging an entire jar out of another jar, then there's probably a way to exclude/substitute the dependency.  Gradle doesn't support dependency management at the class-level, only at the jar-level.